# Select data from XML in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am having trouble in getting some data from a XML text saved in my SQL Server DB. My data is as follow:

```html
<retConsReciCTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="3.00">
  <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
  <verAplic>SP-CTe-25-05-2017</verAplic>
  <nRec>351000011484798</nRec>
  <cStat>104</cStat>
  <xMotivo>Lote processado</xMotivo>
  <cUF>35</cUF>
  <protCTe versao="3.00">
    <infProt>
      <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
      <verAplic>SP-CTe-25-05-2017</verAplic>
      <chCTe>35170623838348000310570000000058731000058731</chCTe>
      <dhRecbto>2017-06-22T21:28:18-03:00</dhRecbto>
      <cStat>232</cStat>
      <xMotivo>Rejeição: IE do destinatário não informada</xMotivo>
    </infProt>
  </protCTe>
</retConsReciCTe>
```

I want to select only the content in . For this reason I am running the following query:

```html
select top 10 retorno_sefaz_doc.value('(/retConsReciCTe/@xmln)[1]','varchar(10)') as [retorno] from documentos
```

And my return is always NULL. Someone could gently give me a help in telling me what is going wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I wanna take the content for atribute versao. In this case, 3.00

Answer (score 2):

You could define a default namespace and `value` to get the output like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    XmlValue xml
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    XmlValue
)
VALUES
(N'<retConsReciCTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="3.00">
  <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
  <verAplic>SP-CTe-25-05-2017</verAplic>
  <nRec>351000011484798</nRec>
  <cStat>104</cStat>
  <xMotivo>Lote processado</xMotivo>
  <cUF>35</cUF>
  <protCTe versao="3.00">
    <infProt>
      <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
      <verAplic>SP-CTe-25-05-2017</verAplic>
      <chCTe>35170623838348000310570000000058731000058731</chCTe>
      <dhRecbto>2017-06-22T21:28:18-03:00</dhRecbto>
      <cStat>232</cStat>
      <xMotivo>Rejeição: IE do destinatário não informada</xMotivo>
    </infProt>
  </protCTe>
</retConsReciCTe>')

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte')
select sd.XmlValue.value('(/retConsReciCTe/@versao)[1]','varchar(20)') 
                                                             AS Versao
FROM @SampleData sd
```

Returns

```
Versao
3.00
```